# Violent Python - Having trouble with OptParse outputting the correct information

Tags: python, optparse

I am working directly from the Violent Python PDF, page 147.

I am currently using the pygeoip module to find the location of IP adresses. I was able to do this first step fairly easily and it is represented by the #1 hash in the code.

The second step includes taking data from a pcap file and matching the corresponding ip addresses (both destination and origin ip's) to their pyschial locations. For some reason, I can't get the program to return this information. Instead I get a printed string from my optParse instance.

my current code is:

```
#1. pg 136 of Violent Python by TJ O'Connor



 #We are using the imported pygeoip module to search the database from
 #http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/geolite/ and match it with an ip address

 import pygeoip

 GI = pygeoip.GeoIP('/home/cody/workspace/violent_python/opt/GeoIP/GeoLiteCity.dat')

 #output should be the location of the given ip; NOTE: does not work for IPV6

 gi = pygeoip.GeoIP('/home/cody/workspace/violent_python/opt/GeoIP/GeoLiteCity.dat')
def printRecord(tgt):
     rec = gi.record_by_name(tgt)
     city = rec['city']
     region = rec['region_code']
     country = rec['country_name']
     long = rec['longitude']
     lat = rec['latitude']
     print '[*] Target: ' + tgt + ' Geo-located.'
     print '[+] ' +str(city)+','+str(lat)+ ',longitude: '+str(long)
 tgt = '173.255.226.98'
 printRecord(tgt)



 #reading a pcap capture; NOTE: it would be useful to learn how to view live
 #traffic via studying pypcap
import dpkt
import socket
def printPcap(pcap):
    for (ts,buf) in pcap:
        try:
            eth = dpkt.ethernet.Ethernet(buf)
            ip = eth.data
            src = socket.inet_ntoa(ip.src)
            dst = socket.inet_ntoa(ip.dst)
            print '[+] Src: ' + src + ' --> Dst: ' + dst
        except:
            pass

 def main():
    f = open('geotest.pcap')
    pcap = dpkt.pcap.Reader(f)
    printPcap(pcap)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()


#create a new function that returns a pyschial location for an IP address
import dpkt, socket, pygeoip, optparse

gi = pygeoip.GeoIP("/home/cody/workspace/violent_python/opt/GeoIP/GeoLiteCity.dat")
def retGeoStr(ip):
    try:
        rec = gi.record_by_name(ip)
        city = rec['city']
        country = rec['country_code3']
        if (city != ''):
            geoLoc = city+' , '+country
        else:
            geoLoc = country
        return geoLoc
    except:
        return 'Unregistered'



#2. this is the entire set up put together

import dpkt,socket,pygeoip,optparse
gi = pygeoip.GeoIP("/home/cody/workspace/violent_python/opt/GeoIP/GeoLiteCity.dat")
def retGeoStr(ip):
    try:
        rec = gi.record_by_name(ip)
        city = rec['city']
        country = rec['country_code3']
        if city != '':
            geoLoc = city + ',' + country
        else:
            geoLoc = country
        return geoLoc
    except:
        return 'Unregistered'
def printPcap(pcap):
    for (ts, buf) in pcap:
        try:
            eth = dpkt.ethernet.Ethernet(buf)
            ip = eth.data
            src = socket.inet_ntoa(ip.src)
            dst = socket.inet_ntoa(ip.dst)
            print '[+] Src: ' + src + '----> Dst: ' + dst
            print '[+] Src: ' +retGeoStr(src) + '----> Dst: ' + retGeoStr(dst)
        except:
            pass

def main():
    parser = optparse.OptionParser('usage%prog -p <pcap file>')
    parser.add_option('-p',dest='pcapFile',type='string',\
    help='specify pcap filename')
(options,args) = parser.parse_args()
    if options.pcapFile == None:
        print parser.usage
        exit(0)
    pcapFile = options.pcapFile
    f = open(pcapFile)
    pcap = dpkt.pcap.Reader(f)
 if __name__ == '__main__':
     main()

'''
 Desiered output:


 analyst# python geoPrint.py -p geotest.pcap
[+] Src: 110.8.88.36 --> Dst: 188.39.7.79
[+] Src: KOR --> Dst: London, GBR
[+] Src: 28.38.166.8 --> Dst: 21.133.59.224
[+] Src: Columbus, USA --> Dst: Columbus, USA
[+] Src: 153.117.22.211 --> Dst: 138.88.201.132
[+] Src: Wichita, USA --> Dst: Hollywood, USA
[+] Src: 1.103.102.104 --> Dst: 5.246.3.148
[+] Src: KOR --> Dst: Unregistered
[+] Src: 166.123.95.157 --> Dst: 219.173.149.77
[+] Src: Washington, USA --> Dst: Kawabe, JPN
[+] Src: 8.155.194.116 --> Dst: 215.60.119.128
[+] Src: USA --> Dst: Columbus, USA
[+] Src: 133.115.139.226 --> Dst: 137.153.2.196
[+] Src: JPN --> Dst: Tokyo, JPN
[+] Src: 217.30.118.1 --> Dst: 63.77.163.212
[+] Src: Edinburgh, GBR --> Dst: USA
[+] Src: 57.70.59.157 --> Dst: 89.233.181.180
[+] Src: Endeavour Hills, AUS --> Dst: Prague, CZE
'''

 #3. we are going to build the kml document to map to google maps
```

My actual output:

```
[*] Target: 173.255.226.98 Geo-located.
[+] Newark,40.7357,longitude: -74.1724
[+] Src: 110.8.88.36 --> Dst: 188.39.7.79
[+] Src: 28.38.166.8 --> Dst: 21.133.59.224
[+] Src: 153.117.22.211 --> Dst: 138.88.201.132
[+] Src: 1.103.102.104 --> Dst: 5.246.3.148
[+] Src: 166.123.95.157 --> Dst: 219.173.149.77
[+] Src: 8.155.194.116 --> Dst: 215.60.119.128
[+] Src: 133.115.139.226 --> Dst: 137.153.2.196
[+] Src: 217.30.118.1 --> Dst: 63.77.163.212
[+] Src: 57.70.59.157 --> Dst: 89.233.181.180
usage%prog -p <pcap file>
```

Please help me! I can't figure this out but I think it has something to do with my parser

Comment: That's a lot of code which is not really supposed to live in one file. (it's a few separate programs really) First limit the code to only the part you want working. Then strip it down to only the part that you have issues with. Then find the solution or ask a more specific question again. Right now you've got a really messy code and you're not even showing how it's being run, yet you ask about issues with parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Like viraptor said, separate the exercises into different script files and then try again. Not only were the exercises written to be in separate scripts, it is far easier to find a bug if you have less code to look through (and less code that can potentially go wrong).

Comment: ok I've tried to break this down a little more clearly and point out what i'm getting stuck on: